# Variable value not passing into mySQL statement in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm passing variables using jQuery to Bootstraps modal through span tags but having issue when running PHP within the modal. The variables all pull through normally but when I try to run mySQL statements, the span tag I store in a variable appears as nothing even though it echos fine. I have given an example of the code below:

HTML:

```
<a role='button' data-topicid='$number' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modaluserinfo' class='modalsend'>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.modalsend').click(function () {
$('span.user-topicid').text($(this).data('topicid'));
});
}); 
</script>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modaluserinfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modaluserinfo" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Details...</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px;">
<?php 
$numberid = "<span class='user-topicid'></span>";
echo $numberid;// THE VALUE ECHOS FINE IN THE MODAL, BUT FAILS TO LOAD IN THE MYSQL QUERY BELOW

$sqlcomment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments.topic_id='$numberid' AND comments.emotions_id='1'");
$commentnumber = mysql_num_rows($sqlcomment);

echo $commentnumber;
?>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My guess is that the PHP statement is running on page load rather than when the modal is opened and the variable is sent to the span tag. Not too sure how to fix this though.

Comment: PHP only runs on the server. So if you want to execute a PHP script after the page has loaded, and without reloading the page, then use XHR to call the PHP script on the server. The PHP script can then send info back to the browser through the XHR object.

Comment: I'm not too sure what XHR is, I'm hoping there's another solution as the variable $numberid echos fine in the modal but doesn't load in the mySQL statement $sqlcomment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved for passing multiple variables using the following method:

HTML:

```
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);

<a role='button' data-topicid='$number' data-page='$page' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modaluserinfo' class='modalsend'>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.modalsend').click(function () {
$('span.user-topicid').load('get_number_comments.php?topicid=' + $(this).data('topicid') + '&page=' + $(this).data('page'));
});
});
```

Refer to @bloodyKnuckles post for any further details

Answer (score 0):

PHP only runs on the server. For the Javascript or jQuery to execute a PHP script a call to the server needs to be made. There's two ways to do that GET (like a link) and POST (like a form). And there's two ways you GET and POST, one way is to reload the page, the other is an XHR object, AKA Ajax.

So, make a separate PHP file, such as...

get_number_comments.php:

```
<?php

// LOAD YOUR DATABASE CREDENTIALS HERE

$numberid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['topicid']);
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);

$sqlcomment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments.topic_id='$numberid' AND comments.emotions_id='1'");
$commentnumber = mysql_num_rows($sqlcomment);

echo $commentnumber;

?>
```

And change your document ready function to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modalsend').click(function () {
        $('span.user-topicid').load('get_number_comments.php?topicid=' + $(this).data('topicid') + '&page=' + encodeURIComponent('<?php echo page; ?>'));
    });
});
```

The inner DIV of your modal now looks like:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px;">
    <span class='user-topicid'></span>
</div>
```

jQuery's load function makes an XHR call to the server, executing the file you enter in the first argument, `get_number_comments.php` in this case. So then `get_number_comments.php` takes the GET variable, safely escapes it, interpolates it in the query, and sends the result back to the page through the XHR object.

(By the way, since PHP `mysql_*` functions are apparently SOON to be null and void I urge you to convert to the PHP `mysqli_*` functions. Then you can also use rigorous database security measures.)

Comment: Thanks a lot - it pulls through the variables now

Comment: Would it be possible to send multiple variables in the .load function? I'd like to send a variable $page, which is a GET variable from the URL listed near the top of the page ($page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);): (e.g. get_number_comments.php?topicid=' + $(this).data('topicid') &page=$page)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - should &page=$page be in quotes like '&page=$page'?

Comment: I've also tried 'get_number_comments.php?topicid=' + $(this).data('topicid') +'&page='+page

Comment: No errors - nothing loads into the modal - the variables don't pull through anymore and yes its a PHP page

Comment: It works with the original: $('span.user-topicid').load('modal_number_comments.php?topicid=' + $(this).data('topicid')); but adding the &page along with the get variable in the PHP file get_number_comments.php fails to load anything

Comment: It doesn't work - I've created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248684/passing-multiple-variables-to-url-using-load/24248906#24248906 with the issue

Comment: Try a test, replace the `'&page=' + '<?=$_GET['page']?>'` with `'&page=' + 'test'`.

Comment: I've tried the test and it works - not sure why the variables not sending to the PHP and I wrote that question before the encodeURIComponent which doesn't work

Comment: At the top of your PHP page, on which this jQuery ready function resides, what exactly does `print_r($_GET['page']);` output?

Comment: It prints out the variable - I have a variable $page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']); as $page is used throughout the PHP where the jQuery function is, but when trying to pass it to get_number_comments.php it doesn't work

Comment: I've done a bit of a work around by passing the $page variable into the data attribute of the a tag - see my answer

Comment: I'm trying to use this approach with pagination and bootstrap tabs, but having issues with the XHR failing to load when clicking the paginated links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344619/pass-php-variables-without-using-href-in-bootstrap-tabs - any ideas?