# Passing Multiple Variables to URL using .load()

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to send multiple variables to PHP using the following statement in jQuery:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modalsend').click(function () {
        $('span.user-topicid').load('get_number_comments.php?topicid=' + $(this).data('topicid') + '&page=' + '<?=$_GET['page']?>');
    });
});
```

It works fine if I pass a single variable in the PHP file like so:

jQuery:

```
$('span.user-topicid').load('get_number_comments.php?topicid=' + $(this).data('topicid'))
```

However, when I try to pass &page=, it fails to pass anything to the PHP file which has the following variables to get the URL:

PHP (get_number_comments.php):

```
$numberid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['topicid']);
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
```

I think it's probably an issue with the markup in the jQuery with the additional &page= but not sure what could be causing it. Note that page is in the URL of the page with the first jQuery function.

NOTE: Issue has been resolved, it is best to get the URL first ($page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);) and send the $page variable in a data attribute just like topicid - please refer to [Variable value not passing into mySQL statement in Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233913/variable-value-not-passing-into-mysql-statement-in-bootstrap-modal/24234234?noredirect=1#comment37456187_24234234) for further details on the solution

Comment: Are you sure you have short tags enabled in PHP? Try `<?php echo $_GET['page'] ?>` instead.

Comment: As a matter of order, try to separate your js code from your php's. Write your php code in js vars then use them to concatenate the querystring

Answer (score 0):

I believe Amin has already answered your question but I just wanted to add that according to the [.load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/), you can pass your data as the second argument and it should handle the encoding.  So you could do something like this:

```
var pageVal= <?=$_GET['page']?>;
var data = { "topicid": $(this).data('topicid'), "page": pageVal };
$('span.user-topicid').load('get_number_comments.php', data);
```

Comment: I think your issue is getting the page number from a PHP variable to a javascript.  Check out my edit above.

Comment: @koolaide, here `var pageVal= <?=$_GET['page']?>;` the assignment needs quoting. But doesn't improve the situation anyway. If you can echo a PHP variable there, you can echo it later.

Answer (score -1):

your problem is in this part `'<?=$_GET['page']?>'`

you can't pass a php code in the location, you either need to send the variable:

`$('span.user-topicid').load('get_number_comments.php?topicid=' + $(this).data('topicid') + '&page=' + page);`

or store the code in a variable and then send it:

```
 var pageVal='<?=$_GET["'+page+'"]?>';
 $('span.user-topicid').load('get_number_comments.php?topicid=' + $(this).data('topicid') + '&page=' + pageVal);
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't load the variables into the PHP file

Comment: @AminJafari What leads you believe you can't pass PHP code in that location? This code works fine for me. Please confirm your assertion.

Comment: Please see the original post - I've edited it with a link to the solution